# How do you get Intellij IDEA to exclude the filtering of large files listed in the maven pom?

Tags: filter, intellij-idea, maven, pom.xml

I keep getting this error whenever I run unit tests in IntelliJ IDEA:

**/home/egervari/IdeaProjects/jobprep-stable/src/main/resources/dict/noun.txt**

**Maven: File is too big to be filtered. Most likely it is a binary file and should be excluded from filtering.**

The thing is, I do explicitly exclude this file:

```
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/environment.${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>src/main/resources/dict**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Is my pom.xml written incorrectly? How do I get IDEA to honor what I actually wrote?

Basically what I want to achieve is make everything in that resources directory part of the classpath, but I only want to filter applicationContext.xml. Basically, I want maven/idea to not touch the other files, because there is 20 meg in there easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution.

```
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/environment.${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/dict</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Tests run much faster now when booting up.

Answer (score 0):

You could also filter based on file types instead of purely location:

```
<includes>
   <include>**/*.xml</include>
   <include>**/*.properties</include>
</includes>
```

There is an `<excludes>` tag also.